# Упростить foreach с использованием linq

Tags: c#

Есть коллекция. Я делаю запрос в бд и если там появились новые записи, я их добавляю в мою коллекцию
Как можно упростить этот кусок кода? Чтобы не использовать foreach, только с помощью linq?

```
      foreach (MyTask task in query)
        {
            if(!currentTaskCollection.Any(item => item.Id == task.Id))
                currentTaskCollection.Add(task);                    
        }
```

Comment: А currentTaskCollection в начале пуста или нет? А в query могут повторяться Id или нет? Вообще ситуация странная, обычно подобной ситуации не возникает.

Comment: Смотря что значит "упростить". С точки зрения "меньше кода" - особо никак. С точки зрения производительности - можно с помощью `HashSet`

Comment: Каков размер коллекции и сколько данных в БД? Можно в запрос в БД передавать айдишники имеющихся записей и получать оттуда только отсутствующие.

Comment: Другой вариант: использовать timestamp/rowversion или аналог и запрашивать из БД только данные с таймстампом больше имеющегося.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

поробуйте так

```
query.ToList().ForEach( task => {
                if(!currentTaskCollection.Any(item => item.Id == task.Id))
                currentTaskCollection.Add(task);
} );
```

Comment: У меня личная неприязнь к использованию `ToList` + `ForEach`. Сперва материализуем запрос - тратим лишнюю память на список. Потом вместо прямого вызова кода загоняем его в лямбду - лишняя косвенность вызова - меньше производительность. И читаемость, имхо, хуже.

Comment: Вопрос такой. Я к примеру стараюсь к такое не делать. Неприязней личных стараюсь не иметь, но есть такое тоже

Answer (score 1):

Я бы, наверное, сделал как-то так, если id в query заведомо не повторяются:

```
idsExcept = currentTaskCollection.Select(x => x.Id).ToHashSet();
currentTaskCollection = currentTaskCollection.Concat(query.Where(x => !idsExcept.Contains(x.Id))
```